# Why does EF Core try to create a new record with an existing ID and how to solve it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am developing a RESTful API using ASP.NET Core on .NET 5. When I try to add a new record to the database using EF Core, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The instance of entity type 'Order' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 2}' is already being tracked.

The stack trace indicates this error occurs in my service class on the `AddAsync` method. It looks like this:

```
public async Task<OrderResponseDto> AddAsync(OrderRequestDto requestDto)
{
    var newOrder = _mapper.Map<Order>(requestDto);
    newOrder.Items = new List<Sandwich>();

    foreach (var item in requestDto.IdsOfOrderedSandwiches)
    {
        var sandwich = await _sandwichRepository.GetByIdAsync(item);
        newOrder.Items.Add(sandwich);
    }

    var createdOrder = await _orderRepository.AddAsync(newOrder);
    return _mapper.Map<OrderResponseDto>(createdOrder);
}
```

The `AddAsync` method in the repository class looks like this:

```
public virtual async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    await _dbContext.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return entity;
}
```

(I have removed some checks, which only throw exceptions.)

I have a seeder class, which adds two Orders, with IDs 1 and 2. So, I expect EF Core to create a new entity with ID 3. however, as can be seen in the exception above: it tries to make a new record with ID 2, which already exists.

Now, I have the following question(s): why does EF Core try to do this and how can I solve this issue? I just want it to create a record with ID 3...

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the full source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to add an `Order` in which you've already given it an ID. If you want EF to generate the ID itself, then you should avoid assigning the ID yourself.

Comment: @Xerillio Thanks. I never set the ID myself. I tested the API using Swagger and there, I removed the ID from the request JSON just to make sure it doesn't think I set it manually.

Comment: @Progman I have, in my opinion, given enough information on what happens, where it happens and how the code looks like. Could you tell me what I should add to this question to make it 'perfect'?

Comment: @JordyDeweer The implementation of `GetByIdAsync()` is missing, the DTO class definitions are missing, the repository implementations are missing, the (AutoMapper?) mapping is missing, the input is missing and maybe the HTTP request is missing. Keep in mind that the value `2` does not fall from the sky, it is most likely coming from an entity or a property value of a DTO object we don't see. That's why you should provide a MCVE, so we can see how the methods are called, what values are used and how you (re)use the `_dbContext` context. There are a lot of unknowns.

Comment: Just for a check. What is the result if you run this command on SSMS _DBCC CHECKIDENT (Order, NORESEED)_ It should print current  identity value that Sql Server thinks it has in its Order table. It should be 2 or greater

Comment: As others commented, there are many unknowns here - `OrderRequestDto` class, `Order` and `Sandwich` entity classes and their fluent configuration if any, context/query tracking behavior, context used by the two repositories (is it one and the same instance?) etc. The line generating exception - because this exception usually is not when *saving*, but when *attaching* (`Add`, `Attach`, `Update`, `Remove` etc.) disconnected entities. So it's not about making the question "perfect",  but *reproducible*, W/o that, we can't tell you what's the problem - all I can say is it is something in your code

Comment: Okay, I fixed it. I won't write an anser since I don't really know how. There are some things I can tell: The answer about AsNoTracking was incorrect, unfortunately. The sandwiches had to be tracked, otherwise EFCore would try to add the existing entities upon creation of an order.

And my appologies for not adding enough code. I was sort of afraid to make this question too long, I guess. I'll keep it in my mind while writing future questions.

The reason why I didn't edit my original question was because I was trying already and was getting closer.

Answer (score 2):

Please use `AsNoTracking()` while you are retrieving data from the database. EF is tracked the PK while updating the entity. In your implementation of the following method

```
await _sandwichRepository.GetByIdAsync(item)
```

you could take as example

```
_context.Set<item>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(a=> a.id = item.id).
```

Comment: Thanks, this made the exception change ;-) (I was mistaken by the way: I forgot I was overriding the method GetByIdAsync somewhere else.)